# SQLite db data access issue

Tags: jquery, html, sqlite

I am developing a site using html5, sqllite & jquery.  i have developed db tables.Products or data which i have added into the tables are visible to be but not to the other PC.he is able to see the db and tables but not the data entered by me. kindly help

Comment: Your database in created in JavaScript?

Comment: How are you saving the data on the server? Not at all, I guess?

Comment: yes, using jquery & javascript i have created tables and inserted data into table.code is  - var data = [fname,lname,u_id,pwd,add1,add2,city,state_val,country_Id,pincode,email_id];  transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO new_user(fname, lname,user_id,password,add1,add2,city,state,country,pincode,email_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",[data[0], data[1], data[2],data[3], data[4], data[5],data[6], data[7], data[8],data[9], data[10]]);

Comment: How do you store the database? Magic? On the server?

Comment: i have created database using below code - var shortName = 'WHOLESALEDB';
         var version = '1.0';
         var displayName = 'Wholesale DB';
         var maxSize = 100000; // in bytes
         WHOLESALEDB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize); and through sqlite database browser i can see database from below path -C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases